# OpenMeetings cannot upload document

Tags: ubuntu, openmeetings

I use OpenMeetings (on Ubuntu 16) and everything is alright except the process of uploading files. If I upload a picture - it's okay. However, if I upload PDF, doc or pptx files - it gives me an error message: 
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aC2I1.png)

[IOErrorEvent type="ioError" bubbles=false cancelable=false eventPhase=2 text= "Error #2032"]

I'm also using Swftools (version 2012-10-15-1307) and edit the "swftools_path" in configuration.
I have no idea what's wrong. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with my OpenMeetings install. I'm only interested in PDF uploads and got exactly the same error.

For PDF uploads, you need the **pdf2swf** tool. This *used* to be part of swftools, but is no longer included in recent distributions.

The solution is to build swftools 0.9.1 or 0.9.2 (the latter has a faulty Makefile, with a quick fix available at http://www.2daygeek.com/install-apache-openmeetings-on-centos-fedora-rhel/ ) from source. Make sure that all prerequisites are installed so that pdf2swf is not skipped when building (the configure process will output a warning listing all skipped tools). After installation, ensure that you can call **pdf2swf** in a terminal.

For LibreOffice/OpenOffice/Office formats you need to install JODConverter. I had little luck getting this to work with the Ubuntu packaged version, but I'm happy enough to have PDF working fine.

Comment: jodconverter is now part of OpenMeetings. You can follow one of very detailed guides from here: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/OPENMEETINGS/Tutorials+for+installing+OpenMeetings+and+Tools